# jQuery code not scanned properly need to simplify it

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to setup a tracking for each element in the main navigation. Everything is working fine, but at some point I started getting the error that the code couldnt be read.

I know that the error is showing up because for every element I am calling it again using 'jQuery':

```
// MAIN CATEGORIES 

// COLLECTION MAIN
    jQuery("#heading-163").one("click", function(e) {
            console.log('category collection tracked');
           exponea.track('main_collection', {
                    action: 'click'
            });
        });

// SLNECNE OKULIARE MAIN
    jQuery("#heading-3").one("click", function(e) {
            console.log('[Jarik was here] category sunglasses tracked');
           exponea.track('main_sunglasses', {
                    action: 'click'
            });
        });

// DIOPTRICKE OKULIARE MAIN
    jQuery("#heading-9").one("click", function(e) {
            console.log('category glasses tracked');
           exponea.track('main_glasses', {
                    action: 'click'
            });
        });

// LYZIARSKE MAIN
    jQuery("#heading-14").one("click", function(e) {
            console.log('category snow goggles tracked');
           exponea.track('main_snow_goggles', {
                    action: 'click'
            });
        });     

// SPORTOVE MAIN
    jQuery("#heading-38").one("click", function(e) {
            console.log('category sportove tracked');
           exponea.track('main_sportove', {
                    action: 'click'
            });
        });     

// ZNACKY MAIN
    jQuery("#heading-48").one("click", function(e) {
            console.log('category brands tracked');
           exponea.track('main_brands', {
                    action: 'click'
            });
        });   

// OUTLET MAIN
    jQuery("#heading-114").one("click", function(e) {
            console.log('category outlet tracked');
           exponea.track('main_outlet', {
                    action: 'click'
            });
        });

    jQuery("#heading-114 > div > div > div > a.outlet_text > img").on("click", function(e) {
            console.log('category outlet left img');
           exponea.track('main_outlet_left_img', {
                    action: 'click'
            });
        });
    jQuery("#heading-114 > div > div > div > a:nth-child(3) > img ").on("click", function(e) {
            console.log('category outlet right img');
           exponea.track('main_outlet_right_img', {
                    action: 'click'
            });
        });

    jQuery('#heading-114 > div > div > div > a:nth-child(3) > button').on("click", function(e) {
            console.log('category outlet btn');
           exponea.track('main_outlet_btn', {
                    action: 'click'
            });
        });
```

my question is, how do I unite this, so I dont have to call the new element everytime with 'jQuery'?

Thank you.

// edit:
[image: this is the error code, it appears after I cross certain lines of code and then the whole code stops working]

this is the error code, it appears after I cross certain lines of code and then the whole code stops working

Comment: Please go read [ask]. Quote error messages _verbatim_ (and add which parts of the code they are referring to, if not obvious), instead of giving us your own vague, unspecific, unclear, paraphrased version of them.

Comment: Can you post the exact error you are getting ?

Comment: @AlexandrosDiamantonis sure I added it into the main post

Comment: this looks like a report on error pre-run. If you delete all lined except 1 jQuery does it result in error ? how are you using `exponea`? Might be that it's not properly initiated and this results in an error that's thrown every time you use it that way

Comment: I think it was caused that I called jQuery to many times. What I did, I created multiple scripts within exponea, and divided the codes there. now it works. but anyway, is there an option to use 'jQuery' just once, like do a var and call all the elements inside it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so here's my stab in the dark...

Not knowing much about your situation I've come up with the below code. I've basically put the config for each tracking event into an array for looping through calling the same piece of code for each time.

It might be a bit overkill and get messy with future variations but it's something ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

The `method` property in the config objects relates to the function you are calling for each item e.g. `jQuery('#heading-163').one(...)` vs `jQuery('#heading-114 > div > div > div > a.outlet_text > img').on(...)`

```js
var trackingMap = [

    // COLLECTION MAIN
    {
        selector: '#heading-163',
        track: 'main_collection',
        method: 'one'
    },

    // SLNECNE OKULIARE MAIN
    {
        selector: '#heading-3',
        track: 'main_sunglasses',
        method: 'one'
    },

    // DIOPTRICKE OKULIARE MAIN
    {
        selector: '#heading-9',
        track: 'main_glasses',
        method: 'one'
    },

    // LYZIARSKE MAIN
    {
        selector: '#heading-14',
        track: 'main_snow_goggles',
        method: 'one'
    },

    // SPORTOVE MAIN
    {
        selector: '#heading-38',
        track: 'main_sportove',
        method: 'one'
    },

    // ZNACKY MAIN
    {
        selector: '#heading-48',
        track: 'main_brands',
        method: 'one'
    },

    // OUTLET MAIN
    {
        selector: '#heading-114',
        track: 'main_outlet',
        method: 'one'
    },
    {
        selector: '#heading-114 > div > div > div > a.outlet_text > img',
        track: 'main_outlet_left_img',
        method: 'on'
    },
    {
        selector: '#heading-114 > div > div > div > a:nth-child(3) > img',
        track: 'main_outlet_right_img',
        method: 'on'
    },
    {
        selector: '#heading-114 > div > div > div > a:nth-child(3) > button',
        track: 'main_outlet_btn',
        method: 'on'
    }
];


/**
 * Loop through tracking map items
 */
for ( var i = 0; i < trackingMap.length; i++ ) {

    /**
     * A single tracking item config
     * @type {Object}
     */
    var trackingItem = trackingMap[ i ];

    /**
     * Check if method property is valid
     */
    if ( typeof jQuery( trackingItem.selector )[ trackingItem.method ] !== 'undefined' ) {

        /**
         * Attach method listener
         */
        jQuery( trackingItem.selector )[ trackingItem.method ]( 'click', function() {
            console.log( trackingItem );

            /**
             * Check that exponea.track exists before calling
             */
            if ( typeof exponea !== 'undefined' && 'track' in exponea ) {
                exponea.track( trackingItem.track, {
                    action: 'click'
                } );
            }

        } );
    }
}
```